# QMl QtControls.Slider returns value with decimal points

Tags: qt, qml

I am using a Slider with below properties set for it -

```
Item {
    id: root
    signal sliderMoved
    property alias value: control.value
    
    QtControls.Slider {
        orientation: Qt.Vertical
        snapMode: QtControls.Slider.SnapOnRelease
        from: 59.0
        to: 86.0
        stepSize : 1.0
        onMoved: root.sliderMoved()
    }
}
```

From user QML where this slider is used thru loader

```
Connections {
    target: sliderLoader.item
    onSliderMoved: {
        console.warn(sliderLoader.item.value);
    }
}
```

But eachtime when the slider is dragged, it returns the value with decimal points. I am expecting value like 59,60,61, 62.....till 86 not like 59.12, 63.45 etc. How to get rid of these decimal points from the returned slider value when the slider is moved

Comment: It works fine for me. I didn't test it in a Loader, but just setting the properties on a Slider the way you show it, it printed integers for me. What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Does it change when you set the `snapMode` to `Slider.SnapAlways`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing decimals is because your slider snapMode is set to snapOnRelease. This means the slider value will not honor your step size until the user releases the slider. Changing to snapAlways will fix this, but it will cause the slider to appear "choppy" during use. If you would still like to use snapOnRelease; I see two options for you moving forward.

Instead of using onMoved to emit sliderMoved, you may use.

```
onPressedChanged: {
    if (!pressed) {
      root.sliderMoved()
    }
  }
```

This way the signal will only be emitted once the slider has been released/snapped, and you will log the whole number value the user has decided upon.

If it is necessary to log every change the user makes as you have it written currently, round up or down as desired in your log statement to prevent decimals in the logs.